# CSS3 Animation On enter scaling timing function

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to get the animation to scale up and down in a bouncy way using the animation timing function.

```
@keyframes iconEnter
  0%
    transform scale(0)
  100%
    transform scale(1)
    animation-timing-function cubic-bezier(.1,.85,.1,1)

.icon
  animation iconEnter 5s
```

This just scales linearly without the timing function being applied. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have added a working snippet. I believe it's working as per your request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 places where you can set a timing function: globally in the same place where you set the animation, or in the keyframes rule.

But, in the latter case, you have always n keyframes and n - 1 time intervals. IN your case, 2 keyframes and 1 time interval.

The timing function stated on a keyframe applies to the time interval that **begins** in this keyframe.

So, the correct way to apply a timing function on the keyframes would be on the first one:

```css
@keyframes iconEnter {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.1);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.25,8,.25,-8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}


div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: tomato;
    transform: scale(0.1);
}
body:hover div {
    animation: iconEnter 4s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are expecting with the time function; it's working for me on Chrome 59.

That being said...

I am able to get the desired result using [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), [TranslateX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) and [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

The code can be greatly shortened but I left everything there for **demo purposes.**

*(rough)* Working example:

```css
@keyframes iconEnter {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.1) translatey(30px)
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translatey(-30px)
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translatey(30px)
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translatey(-30px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translatey(30px)
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translatey(-30px)
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translatey(30px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translatey(-30px)
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(0.9)translatey(30px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translatey(0deg)
  }
}

.icon {
  animation: iconEnter 10s;
  border-radius: 100vw;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" class="icon">
```

Comment: Thanks I wish to use timing function rather than make the whole thing out of keyframes though.

Comment: @Harry Yeah, it would be much better that way, however, since you're animating the scale of the object alone I think you're limited to movement on the z-axis because that's where the scale occurs and that's how the current timing function works. I could be totally wrong though

Answer (score 1):

first of allyou need to set the timing function to the icon, not in the keyframes, but i'm not sure, if this is what you want? if you want the icon to scale up, then down, then up again you need to add steps inbetween 0% and 100%

```css
@keyframes iconEnter{
  0%{
    transform: scale(0);
    
    }
  100%{

    transform: scale(1);
    }
}
    
.icon{
  position:absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  animation: iconEnter  5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">

</div>
```

Comment: I want to control the scaling from the function instead of using the keyframes. Maybe a different function makes the "bouncing" more obvious? `cubic-bezier(.1,.85,.1,1)`

Comment: I don't think putting the animation function in the icon is correct. I read that it applies the function to every step of the animation? Rather I would like it to play just once but on the animation as a whole.

Comment: i think it might be helpful if you read a little bit more on animations. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) for example. the timing function is part of the animation property. The function declares when  the different keyframes are applied. You can read more on that [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/04/understanding-css-timing-functions/) 
if you add more steps to your keyframe you could get the effect you want

Comment: yes I understand I can, but I would like to learn to use the timing function instead. It's easier and cleaner than creating keyframes.

Comment: then try out [this](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/).
i'm really not sure what you want to do here. there's no "using timing function instead" you use a combination of both. it's **animation**-timing-function. or do you perhaps want to use `transition` instead of `animation`?